# Need method in Firefox to determine lost canvas/context

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, firefox

In Firefox, specifically, I've been having problems with canvases that end up being blank after the tab has been idle for a long time. The following event exists, however, it is not implemented in Firefox:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/contextlost_event

Other than assuming all contexts have been lost and redrawing all of them any time I regain focus, or manually checking to see if every pixel is blank (performance won't allow this) is there perhaps any variable in the CanvasRenderingContext2D itself that could be checked to determine if a redraw is necessary in Firefox?

Comment: Don't you need to check *just one* pixel on `visibilitychange` ?

Comment: @Dimava, no when working with transparent images there's a high chance that the correct value of a pixel will be 0,0,0,0